# Reusing layouts for fragments for one activity multiple fragments

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-jetpack

I am currently learning the one activity + multiple fragments approach, which is recommended by Google. I want to share some layouts between the fragments: toolbar, scrollbar, app bar.

What is the best way of doing this?

for example this app in GitHub:
https://github.com/mitchtabian/Open-API-Android-App

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate layout file for each of the layouts you're trying to reuse. You can then include those in your fragments' layouts - you do this via the `<include>` tag.

Example layout for a toolbar (toolbar.xml):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

example of reusing this:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

There's good documentation on how to achieve this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts).

Comment: I know how to do this with toolbars. I want do the same with coordinate layouts and nested scroll views

Comment: it's the same principle. extract the layout you want to reuse to a separate file and include it wherever you want to reuse it.